# iOS Chart draw horizontal line issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios-charts

I use in my project ios-charts swift library(https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) and setting the graph I get this:

https://postimg.org/image/5sj4wktnb/

(if you need code I will post it)

I want to delete those horizontal lines but I can’t be able.

Do you help me?

Answer (score 2):

**This is working for me**

**swift 5**

```
 lineChart.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
 lineChart.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
 lineChart.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
 lineChart.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
```

Answer (score -1):

This might help you for the left axis :

```
[YOUR_CHARTVIEW.leftAxis setDrawGridLinesEnabled:NO];
```

If you have vertical lines, then hide lines for the axis :

```
[YOUR_CGHARTVIEW.xAxis setDrawGridLinesEnabled:NO];
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you have both objective-c and swift tagged, to hide the horizontal lines on the chart in **Swift** it should be something like:

```
chartView.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
```

Where `chartView` is your view object.

I don't believe you can/need to do it for the right axis, though I usually turn off the right axis labels anyway.

Similarly, the way you disable the vertical lines in swift is:

```
chartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
```

In case anyone is interested in the swift equivalents.

Answer (score -1):

For Swift, you can use below line to hide the grid lines of X-Axis by following line:-

```
yourChartView.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
```

For Objective-C, you can use the following line of code to solve this issue.

```
xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = NO;
```